# Generate Xml file using a dataset and a XSD file in Vb

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, dataset

How can I generate an Xml file using dataset, filled by a database, that follow rules in XSD file?

Edit:

This is what I wrote:

```
        ' Create a DataSet with one table 
        ' containing two columns and 10 rows.
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("dataSet")
        Dim table As DataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add("Items")
        table.Columns.Add("id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("Item", Type.GetType("System.String"))

        ' Add ten rows
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 9
            row = table.NewRow()
            row("id") = i
            row("Item") = "Item" & i
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next


        Dim strm As StreamReader = New StreamReader("schema.xsd")
        Dim filename As String = "output.xml"
        Dim stream As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
        dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(strm)
        dataSet.WriteXml(stream)
```

I changed the XSD file, renaming the elements like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="dataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="dataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Items">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="id-test" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="Item-test" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But when i generate XML file the name of the elements are still id and item.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how these could solve my problem.
I need a way to use rules in XSD file on dataset for create XML file.

Could you make a little code example?

Ty for your time :)

Comment: What I want to say, that you need to show here what did tried and where you are stuck. Now it seems like you ask to make your "home work" without any effort from you. Check this for example [Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx#xmlgen_topic2)

Comment: post edited.

I downloaded the xmlSampleGenerator but i don't know how to use it in my vb project.
I tried to import using tool -> external tool, but seams doesn't work.

Comment: maybe i should try to create the dataset first, using xsd file, and then fill it with records of database... btw i don't know how to do that :/ (internet sugget to use xml.exe)

Comment: Try fill `DataSet` with your data. Then read data and using XmlWriter create xml

Comment: no, is not what i have to do. 
I need to trasform dataset using a particular XSD,
probably the best way to proceed is to create dataset with the instructions in XSD file and then fill it with records.